# How to exclude menu link from jQuery click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My project is using a simple toggle menu and I need to exclude the last link (#blog) from the click handler doing scroll animations and URL modifications.

Here is HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </span>
            <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-links">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-links">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#skillset" class="nav-links">Skillset</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-links">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="blog" href="#https://anzudev.blogspot.com/" target="_blank" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And here jQuery:

```
$('nav a[href*="#"]').not("#blog").on("click", function () { 
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top }, 1000);
  });
```

I've added a jQuery click handler to all nav-links to smoothly scroll to that section and modify the URL accordingly. However, I need to exclude the #blog nav-link, since that redirects to an external site. I've tried the following selectors:

```
 - $('nav a[href*="#"]').not("#blog")
 - $('nav a[href*="#"]').not(":last")
```

But upon clicking "#blog" will still attempt to go to myurl.com/#https://anzudev.blogspot.com/ instead of an external link.

I have a simple mockup of my code [here on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/dyPeJZE) for testing.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong here? Cheers!

Comment: In `codepen` when I click on `blog` it open a link in new tab, and didn't scroll down, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to delete the `#` from the beginning of the blog link URL:

`https://anzudev.blogspot.com/`

instead of

`#https://anzudev.blogspot.com/`

Anything starting with `#` will be attached to the end of current page URL.

Working edited CodePen: https://codepen.io/liquidmetalrob/pen/gObzvOg?editors=1010

Comment: @AnzuPai No problem. Just to be clear, there is nothing wrong with your jQuery code. The function doesn't get run when you click the Blog link. You can test it by putting a `console.log()` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your href link on your blog should just be:

```
"https://anzudev.blogspot.com/"
```

and not

```
"#https://anzudev.blogspot.com/"
```

Comment: guess who feels extra silly now! thank you very much :)